# How does line width work when drawing a line in Android Studio?

Tags: android, drawing

I'm using Android Studio and trying to draw a `Rectangle`. I'm slightly confused about the "geometry" of it... wondered whether anyone knows how it works.

Essentially, I'm drawing it with coordinates `(0,0,canvas_width, 0.5 * canvas_height)`, so I should get a rectangle which is half the height of the canvas, and the full width. The line has thickness 5, and I'm doing Stroke only, no Fill.

It looks as though the top, right and left sides are thinner than the bottom sides - the bottom side being the only one which is not against the edge of the canvas.

Does Android Studio draw the Rectangle with half the border on each side of the coordinate (if that makes sense)? So in order to create a rectangle which has the same border all round, I'd need to double the line width on the top, right and left sides? Or start it at `(5,5)` or `(2.5, 2.5)` instead of `(0,0)`?  Is that correct?

And if I draw a Rectangle which goes from, say `(10,10)` to `(20,20)`, with a border width of 2, the internal dimensions of the rectangle would be 6x6? Or 8x8?

Hope that makes sense - I can draw some diagrams to illustrate it if not.

Comment: `Rect r = new Rect(0,0,canvas_width, 0.5 * canvas_height); r.inset(5/2f, 5/2f); canvas.drawRect(...)` - of course this is just illustration: in real code its not wise to create a `new Rect` inside `onDraw` method...

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: sure, no problem

Comment: Why isn't it wise to create a new Rect in onDraw? I'm not doing that here, as it happens, but why would it be a problem?

Comment: because `onDraw` may be called bazillion times (for example when using animations) so its better to use `Rect r` as a field, not a local variable

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks!

Comment: at your service... ;-)